# Quiz app option button background color change

Tags: ios, swift

When we click on the wrong option in the quiz application, the background color is red and the background color of the correct option is green. how can I do that? My model :

```
struct QuizModel  {
    let q : String
    let a : [String]
    let correctAnswer : Int
}
```

my question :

```
QuizModel(q: "Aşağıdakilerden hangisi ilk yardımın amaçlarından biri değildir?", a: [
        "A) İlaçla tedavi etmek","B) Durumun kötüleşmesini önlemek","C) Hayati tehlikeyi ortadan kaldırmak","D) Yaşamsal fonksiyonların sürdürülmesini sağlamak"], correctAnswer: 0)
```

answer func :

```
 func checkAnswer(userAnswer : Int)-> Bool {
          if userAnswer == quiz[questionNumber ].correctAnswer {
              return true
          }else{
              return false
          }
      }
```

user tapped option button :

```
 @objc func TappedButton(_ sender : UIButton){
        
        let userAnswer = sender.tag
    
        
        let userRightGot = quizBrains.checkAnswer(userAnswer: userAnswer)
        
        
        if userRightGot {
            sender.backgroundColor = .green
            
            score += 1
            scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
        }else{
            
            sender.backgroundColor = .red

            failScore += 1
            failScoreLabel.text = "\(failScore)"
        }
```

Comment: what's the problem ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method affects only the currently tapped button, you have to update the state of the other buttons, too.

Something like this, `button0`-`button3` are the references to the buttons, you have to add IBOutlets if there are none.

```
var buttons = [button0, button1, button2, button3]

// please name methods with starting lowercase letter
@objc func tappedButton(_ sender : UIButton) {
    
    let userAnswer = sender.tag
    let correctAnswer = quiz[questionNumber].correctAnswer
    for button in buttons {
        button.backgroundColor = button.tag == correctAnswer ? .green : .red
    }
    if userAnswer == correctAnswer {
       score += 1
       scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    } else {
       failScore += 1
       failScoreLabel.text = "\(failScore)"
    }    
}
```

Comment: or `@IBOutlet weak var buttons: [UIButton]!` then assign the buttons

Comment: Vadian is good man. but the only problem is that when you click on one of the options, the background color of all the options changes.

Comment: Also, after clicking the option once, other options should not be clicked.